# Graph x^3 - y^2 - y = 0 using tikzpicture environment [Overleaf]

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*}}
\pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=red,fill=white,very thick,only marks,mark=*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}                                                          
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            legend pos=outer north east,
            axis lines = center,
            label style={font=\tiny},
            legend style={font=\tiny},
            xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            clip=false,
            legend style={cells={align=left}}
        ]
        \addplot[red,thick] {x*x*x-y*y-y};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Original graph]

Overleaf throws me the following error:

> ! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, you can't use 'y' in this context. PGFPlots expected to sample a line, not a mesh. Please use the [mesh] option combined with [samples y>0] and [domain y!=0:0] to indicate a twodimensional input domain.

so I change

```
\addplot[red,thick] {x*x*x-y*y-y};
```

for

```
\addplot[samples y>0, domain y!=0:0,red,thick] {x*x*x-y*y-y};
```

but now 4 errors appears, and when using `addlegendentry` the picture is [image: Mesh picture] instead of the normal line.

I would like to graph the implicit function like this:

[image: What I want]

**not using gnuplot.** Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wish to plot `x^3-y^2-y=0`, which is equivalent to `x^3=y^2+y` or `x=sign(y^2+y)\cdot|y^2+y|^{1/3}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,title=lul]
    \addplot[red,domain=-1.1:0.6,samples=101] 
    ({sign(x*x+x)*pow(abs(x*x+x),1/3)},x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]